# What is the syntax for await with an event handler for pouchdb?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, pouchdb, ecmascript-2016

I want to rewrite the following using async/await

```
db.replicate.from(remoteCouch).on(
  'complete', (info) => {
     db.sync(remoteCouch, { live: true, retry: true })
   })
```

How do I handle the `on` event using await?

---

Would

```
var res = await db.replicate.from(remote)
res.on('complete',  (info) => {
   db.sync(remote, opts)
})
```

work?

Do I need an extra async/await on the callback?

Comment: wrap it in a promise like any other callback function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#replication) on `replicate()`, the object returned by `.from()` actually satisfies the interface of a `Promise`.

In general, API calls made through PouchDB return objects that can work like a `Promise`, according to the [API Overview](https://pouchdb.com/api.html):

> If you don’t specify a callback, then the API returns a promise. In
>   supported browsers or Node.js, native promises are used, falling back
>   to the minimal library lie as needed.

Comment: have expanded the question with your answer

Comment: @sureshvv, it looks you're using the `complete` event for control flow, to sequence your `db.sync()` call after your `replicate()` call.  If this is indeed the case, you should be able to run `db.sync()` and/or `await` it after your call to `db.replicate()`.